# function(data) is not get called in $.getJSON in rhomobile

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, rhomobile

I have following code in javascript callback function of body load:

```
 alert("calling get json");
 $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/books/show.json", {book: 3}, function(data) 
 {
         alert("data received");
 });
```

After getting alert of 'calling get json' being called,the server return status  200 ok.
still control is not passing to function(data) and alert of 'data received' is not called.

 so,what is wrong?

Comment: I suspect this may be a Cross Origin Policy problem. Are you sure the server does send 200ok? The domain (localhost) and port (3000) used in the Ajax request must be the same as the ones of the http server that serves your web page.

Comment: server returns 200 OK ,also I have written at rails server-side code to accept CORS requests